# how to replace user input in a function

Tags: python

I am trying to write user choice into text file. this works perfect. User choice is like:

1

2

3

..

```
def write_log(name, total):
   # This writes a passed info into text
   logfile = open("text.txt", "a")

   towrite = name
   towrite += " "
   towrite += total
   towrite += "\n"

   try:
       logfile.write(towrite)
   finally:
       logfile.close()

   return write_log
```

I am trying to replace user choice with another names. 
something like this:

```
change = [(1, triangle), (2, square), (3, rectangle), (4, pentagon)]
```

when i do this it does not work

```
def write_log(name, total):
   # This writes a passed info into text
   change = [(1, triangle), (2, square), (3, rectangle), (4, pentagon)]
   for search, replace in change:
      name = name.replace(search, replace)
   logfile = open("text.txt", "a")

   towrite = name
   towrite += " "
   towrite += total
   towrite += "\n"

   try:
       logfile.write(towrite)
   finally:
       logfile.close()

   return write_log
```

Comment: Shouldn't `triangle, square, rectangle, pentagon` be strings?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary:

```
def write_log(name, total):
   change = {1: 'triangle', 2: 'square', 3: 'rectangle', 4: 'pentagon'}

   name = change.get(name, 'other')
   towrite = "%s %d\n" % (name, total)
   logfile = open("text.txt", "a")

   try:
       logfile.write(towrite)
   finally:
       logfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would use:

```
def write_log(name, total):
    #{n} is better than to replace a number if it's user input,
    #where n is the index of each item in change. I.E {0} == change[0] == "triangle"
    change = ["triangle", "square", "recrangle", "pentagon"]#remember that {n} refers to a position in this list.
    towrite = "%s %s\n" % (name.format(*change), total)
    with open("text.txt", "a") as logfile:#With closes a file automatically for you, in fewer lines.
        logfile.write(towrite)
```

If you want string substitution in total you do:

```
towrite = "%s %s\n" % (name.format(*change), total.format(*change))
```

And if "*change" does not work you could do the list unpacking yourself (name.format("triangle", "rectangle"...))

Good luck :)